# i have a code igniter mysql database error in this what should i do to change in database?

Tags: mysql

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'brewers_check' in 'field list'

```
SELECT `token`, `brewers_check`, `status` 
FROM students use index (id) 
WHERE `id` = '9' 
ORDER BY `id` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Filename: models/Db_model.php

Line Number: 66

Comment: Is `brewers_check` a valid column name?

Comment: the program never is wrong, you should check for typos on both sides